# Fixed radius nearest neighbours, with sets

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, computational-geometry, nearest-neighbor, kdtree

I need to efficiently solve the following problem, a variant of the [Fixed radius nearest neighbours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-radius_near_neighbors) problem:

> Given a list of n sets S, where each set S[i] consists of (2-dimensional) input points, and a query point q: List the indices of all sets in S such that at least one point of the set is within distance 'r' of q.

Approaches involving range trees, k-d trees and similar data structures storing all the points solve this in running times similar to O(log(n) + k), where n is the total number of points, and k is the number of results (points) returned. My problem is that each set is quite large, and while I can deal with large values of n, large values of k make my algorithm run very slowly and consume prohibitive amounts of space, when I actually only need the indices of the valid sets rather than all of the individual points or nearest point in each set.

If I make randomized k-d trees of each set, and then query for q in each set, (correct me if I'm wrong), I can solve the problem in O(m*log(n/m)) amortized time, where m is the number of the sets, which is a significant improvement over the first approach, but before implementing it, I wonder if there are other better practical ways of solving the problem, especially as m and n can become 10x or more of what they are now, and I am also concerned about the space/memory used in this approach. Elements could also be added to the sets, which may make the k-d trees unbalanced, and may require frequent reconstructions.

Other approaches I've tried involve partitioning the 2-d space into grids, and then using bloom filters, (and taking their union), but that that takes a prohibitive amount of space, and I still need to query for m sets. I also can't use a disjoint set to compute unions, because the points in each partition are not disjoint, and cannot be made disjoint.

Current values I am working with:

Total number of points: 250 million (could become 10x larger)

Number of sets: 50,000

The number of points in a set are thus, on average, ~5,000, but there are  sets having 200,000+ points.

Values of k (number of matching *points*), for radii of interest: up to 40 million when there are 250 million points. The points are very densely clustered in some places. Even for such a large value of k, the number of matching *sets* is only 30,000 or so.

I'd welcome an approach which involves "once you've found any point in the set within the radius, don't bother about processing other points in the set." Any other approach that solves this problem efficiently, is of course, equally welcome.

I don't have to store the entire data structure in memory, I can store the structure in a database and retrieve parts that are needed.

On a side note, I'd also appreciate if someone could point me to a well-tested k-d tree implementation in Java, which at least works well for 2 dimensions, and serializes and deserializes properly.

Comment: I do not understand the requirement *"... such that at least one point of s[i] is within distance 'r' of q."*. You cannot ensure this condition while querying the data. When there is no such point within radius `r` around `q`, the query will inevitably return an empty set. I would understand requirements like *"return all points within radius r around q"* or *"return nearest point from q"*.

Comment: ... or *"return nearest N points from q"*.

Comment: E.g., see: https://robowiki.net/wiki/User:Rednaxela/kD-Tree

Comment: The points are partitioned into sets. For a query point q, I need the names or labels of all sets which have (one or more) points which are within radius r of q. Of course there are sets which have no such points - those are the sets that I don't want in my output. Thanks for the library, will check it out.

Comment: Do you really need that many neighbors ? Can't you consider the k-nearest neighbors with k imposed ?

Comment: Its not about the number of neighbours at all. Its about the sets, and yes, I need all the sets.

Comment: Another way to formulate the problem - given a point p, and given n k-d trees, can I efficiently, i.e without traversing via all k-d trees,  report which k-d trees contain a point within radius r of p?

Comment: Update: I used the approach I described in the question, that is, making KD trees of sets, and then querying each KD tree. Since the points were latitudes & longitudes, I multiplied by 100, and rounded off to the nearest integer, to reduce the space taken, while trading away some accuracy. Works fast enough. Also figured out how to scale horizontally by doing this in a distributed manner.